# How to do some task in background after kill the application

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, background-process

i am doing one application.In that one task is running in background every time.My problem is,if i kill the application then that task also stopped.But i want to run that task after application killed by user.How to do this one.

Comment: And thats good. I dont want an app running in background without my knowledge and no way to stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to run any kind of processes in the background after user kills the application. See what Viber does for their app.

[image]

So you can give a notice to user not to quit the app, but you would have to give them a valid reason. And if your app is not GPS or Music app your app will not be active in the background and you all your processes will be suspended by the OS to save battery life.

Comment: If you have any legal apple document for this ? if you have then kindly provide link, because i have to prove that apple is not allowing any background process after kills the application.
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Apple doesn't allow you to background execution after user kill the apps. If your app in background and you want to perform some execution. you can do this. Using background service of apple. but iOS will kill the app after 3 mins.(Some geeks said you get 10 mins. but i try to implement it, i found that 3 mins is max limit from apple) but apple allows longer run for app in background in only special cases. 
[Explore this for better understanding](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)

Answer (score 1):

After killing the application we can't run the background task programatically. 
But we can trigger the background task using push notification. For that some time limit(30sec) is there to finish the task. Check

`-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` this method..

Link: [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)

Comment: We no need to give some time to complete the task.It's needs to run continuosly.

Comment: We cant take our own time to finish the task. As per doc, os will provide 30 sec to download/process the task. We need to finish the task within the time.

Comment: If we use the locations services,or voip or audio then we can runt he app in background right.So if i use any thing in this list,and i kill the app and i need to run that task.