# How to use NSTimer after kill the application in iOS 10

Tags: ios

I am using NSTimer for getting location according to time, no matter location updated or not because **didUpdateLocations** is working fine in background, after kill the app but need location according to time because my timer is working fine in Background but after kill or terminate app it not working.

Please help me for work my timer after kill my app.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1 for general information on how to manage tasks while in the background. See also https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1 for specific information on gathering location information in the background. NSTimer is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 2):

`Not possible` handle timer after kill application.

Base on my experience we cant handle on our hand after application kill. `apple policy` after application `kill` nothing to process in background or etc.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28286577/3752143)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13115324)

Comment: Ok i changed link @CalebKleveter

Answer (score 2):

Timers do not "run" in the way you're thinking. There is no "count down." A timer simply adds a marker to a run loop to send a certain message at a certain time. Every time the runloop runs, it checks to see if any of the timers have expired (if "now" is later than their fire date). If so, it sends the requested message the same way it does other things like call drawRect: or process a touch event or the like. It's more or less a giant while (true) loop where one of the things in the loop is "fire expired timers."

So what does all of that mean? It means that timers are only going to fire when the given runloop is being "pumped" (processed). Usually this is the main runloop, and it only gets processed while your application is active. If you become inactive (generally when the user navigates to another app), then the runloop won't process. All the timers that expire while you're inactive will fire when you come back (which is why you usually want to invalidate timers before going into the background). (Non-main runloops are a little more complicated, but pretty rare. They still won't run indefinitely in the background, though, but there are more cases where they fail to run.)

On the other hand, if you're terminated (which can happen without notice while you're in the background), then your runloops are all gone. When you relaunch, your timers won't be instantiated. That's your job if you want it. So you can't rely on your timers ever firing.

Because you've included `repeats:YES`, the timer will be rescheduled for you automatically. Again, this doesn't mean it "counts down" or is "still running" or anything like that. It just means that when it fires, it automatically schedules another timer event. So if the user just sits at the "OK" button for long enough, the timer will fire again (in iOS; things can be a little different on Mac and "modes" matter more there).

Note that there is no reason to call both `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:..`. and also addTimer:... The "scheduled" part of the method means that the timer has already been added to the runloop.

Answer (score 1):

when the app is in the background, you can do that. However when the user intentionally terminates the app, or your app terminates itself (3 minutes of inactivity) then you loose all your previliges and your app cant do anything but listen get notofocations (if you have notofocations implemented)

If you are trying to forbid you app to terminate, you can let it run a silent mp3 in that background that way your app is always active (drains battery).

But if the user double tap home button and swipe up your app (terminates it). There is nothing you can do!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Playing silent audio is forbidden in the App Store, Apple will reject the app if it is attempted to be published.